# installing facebook apk on android emulator via adb endless processing

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator, adb

facebook apk dose not istalled using adb install command, on command line windows.

After hitting enter, it outputs the size and time and then no progress for Hours.
See Snap: 
[image]

Somebody help..

Or is there any other method? 
Thanks